# are there java method naming conventions are in use for mutable `with`?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

IMPORTANT: I am NOT asking for an opinion on what naming convention I should use. I want to know what naming conventions others have seen for the case below, in projects large and public enough to be noteworthy. Unfortunately, my Google searches have turned up nothing, probably because I don't already know any of the prefixes and therefore can't search for it by name.

I know that the `with` method prefix should be used to return a new instance of an immutable object, with its contents modified according to the specified object. However, I’m not aware of any naming convention for simply mutating a mutable object. Is anyone aware of any naming conventions for this and where they’re used?

If it matters, the problem I want to solve is I want to add a method that initializes the contents of an existing DTO, using a corresponding entity.

Comment: "I’m not aware of any naming convention for simply mutating a mutable object" — you mean setters? Like `setFoo(Foo foo)` ?

Comment: @khelwood: AFAIK `set` is used to set a single specified property to the specified value--for example, `setWidth(15)`. If you've seen it used to initialize an entire object, please write an answer citing where you've seen it.

Comment: @Michael: I don't have two DTOs; I have one DTO and one entity. I want to set the properties in the DTO based on the properties in the entity. In this case the properties in each are likely similar, but depending on whatever conventions are out there they don't have to be. But I imagine the case still holds if I want to set the properties of one object based on the properties of another object of the same type.

Comment: Then what you're describing is an anti-pattern. DTO should simply contain an Entity, and the method should be called `setEntity`. Why would you declare analogous fields in two distinct places? DRY.

Comment: @Michael: That's an opinion--exactly what I don't want. Anyway, in that case subsequent changes to the entity would result in the DTO changing, which I don't want. Also, the getters/setters are currently generated by Lombok; I would have to write my own getters with your method. Also, you're not really removing any complexity--merely moving it to multiple methods (the getters) instead of a single method. Your method would actually require manually writing more lines of code for a less suitable solution.

Comment: If anything, your current implementation *more tightly couples* the implementation of DTO to Entity. Your point about Lombok makes no sense with regards to my suggestion.

Comment: @Michael: Once again, this is all a matter of opinion so I won't answer any more questions along this line. In my case, I'm actually extending a base class using generics, so the DTO is not tightly coupled to any particular object unless you want it to be. The base class code itself isn't coupled to any object--the only code that's tightly coupled is the code that converts the entity's properties to the DTO's properties. That code is by definition always tightly coupled, and in this case it's "better" (opinion) because is separated from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard convention for the scenario you're describing. Take a look at a `GsonBuilder` ([documentation here](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html)). There are many prefixes used, including "set", "add", "register", "enable", etc. They all just describe the method's behavior.

I would recommend using `initializeFromEntity(entity)` or something similar, since this describes what the method does -- you're initializing the DTO contents using an entity.

Searching Google for "Java initializeFrom" results in several usages ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69533_01/Platform.11-3/apidoc/atg/beans/DynamicBeanState.html#initializeFrom-java.lang.Object-), [example](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fdebug%2Fui%2FlaunchConfigurations%2FJavaLaunchTab.html)).

Comment: No methods in the cited documentation even remotely matches the criteria laid out in the question.

Comment: I added some examples of `initializeFrom` methods.

Comment: Ok, that's more like what I was looking for.

Comment: Yep, `initializeFrom` seems pretty prevalent. Thanks!